# Producing symbols from HTML characters in FPDF

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, special-characters, fpdf

I have a government client that requires the legal 'section symbol' (§) in their documents.  When creating the documents in a web page, this symbol is created with `&sect;` or `&#167;`.

I can not figure out how to get either of these to work in a pdf document created with FPDF.  I have tried the iconv and utf8_decode methods, but neither have worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Comment: Thanks for this. I need to add flag as "ENT_XHTML" and encoding as "ISO-8859-1". Then it works for me. html_entity_decode("&pound;", ENT_XHTML,"ISO-8859-1")

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier approach to do this:

You can generate a section symbol using FPDF with using ascii code: `chr(167)`.

It's good practice to make this a constant. At the top of your script, add:

```
define('SECTION',chr(167));
```

Now you can use `SECTION` in your script to print the euro symbol.
For example:

```
echo SECTION.'1.1';
```

Will output: `§1.1`

Note: This will also work for other symbols with `chr(ascii)`, where `ascii` is the ascii code of the symbol. You can find an overview of ascii codes on this page: `http://www.atwebresults.com/ascii-codes.php?type=2`